# In R, dataframe[-NULL] returns an empty dataframe

Tags: r, indexing

I'm creating some routines in `R` to ease model creation and to distinguish several groups based on several parameters *(ex: original watches VS fakes ones using watches common attributes).*

During the proccess, I keep track of the potential excluded lines in a vector (empty at first), and I get ride of them at the end using:

```
    model$var <- raw_data[-line_excluded,]
```

The problem is that if `line_excluded` is `c()` (ndlr no line exlcuded), `model$var` is an empty dataframe then in that case I want all the lines of the dataframe.

The only solution I have think about is the us of

```
if (!is.null(line_excluded)){
    model$var <- raw_data[-line_excluded,]}
```

But that's not really pretty, and I have several `tracking variables` as `line_excluded` which need that.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try:

```
model$var <- raw_data[!(1:nrow(raw_data) %in% line_excluded),]
```

This is similar to what @THomasIsCoding suggested, you look for the row numbers that are not in your line_excluded..

Answer (score 2):

You can make it in another way using `setdiff()`, which can deal with empty `line_excluded` i.e.,

```
model$var <- raw_data[setdiff(seq(nrow(raw_data)),line_excluded),]
```